# How to stop support for large and xlarge screen for an app already in the market

Tags: android, android-manifest

Initial AndroidManifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
```

New AndroidManifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>


<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"

 />
```

When I try to upload the new version, the market still shows supported screens to be small-xlarge (For the latest uploaded APK, which is still inactive. Not for the active APK).

I tried compatible-screens but it seems that its not available for API 8.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried adding an `android:minSdkVersion` attribute to the `uses-sdk` tag?

Comment: Thats the first line in the snippets above.

Comment: Oops. I meant to write `android:targetSdkVersion`. I think there's an interaction with compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supports-screen did not work for me while trying to remove support for large and xlarge screens and keeping small and normal screens.

I am quite new to Android so my solution might be obvious to few of you, but here it is in any case.

My project was build using API level 8 and had minSDKVersion of 8 too. So I changed the API level to 10 while keeping minSDK to 8. Plus, I removed support-screens and used compatible-screens instead as support-screens was still not filtering out the unsupported screen sizes.

Now when I upload my app, it shows the current screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on when you updated it, it can take up to 1 to 2 days to update. As ive ran into this issue in the pass. You may just need to give it some time.

Comment: I tried to upload an app with smallscreen="false" and it immediately showed that the new APK will support normal-xlarge screens. I did not activate the new APK, just uploaded it.

Comment: hmm..That is interesting. It seems like everything in your manifest is correct. The android market does act weird alot. Ive had problems with this same thing in the pass. I just gave it some time.